# How to use `this` and `_this` (fat arrow) using coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, d3.js

I'm using the D3 function `each`, which accepts a callback function and calls it passing `this` as argument, but I need to access both `this` and `_this`. This is the coffeescript code:

```
@x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(@model.geneExpressions[0].length)).rangeBands([0, width])    

getRow = (row) =>
    cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
        .data(row)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d,i) => @x(i))    

rows = @heatmap.selectAll(".row")
    .data(@model.geneExpressions)
  .enter().append("g")
    .each(getRow)
```

and the javascript that it generates:

```
    var _this = this;    

this.x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(this.model.geneExpressions[0].length)).rangeBands([0, width]);    

getRow = function(row) {
        var cell;
        return cell = d3.select(_this).selectAll(".cell").data(row).enter().append("rect").attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return _this.x(i);
        })
      };    

rows = this.heatmap.selectAll(".row").data(this.model.geneExpressions).enter().append("g").attr("class", "row").each(getRow);
```

How can I get coffeescript to use `this` instead in this line and leave everything the same?:

```
return cell = d3.select(this) ...
```

The problem is that I can't pass @x as an argument to `each` and use the thin arrow instead of the fat arrow (because then I couldn't access @x), unless I rewrite the D3 function, which seems overkill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you have this structure:

```
@x = ...
getRow = (row) =>
    d3.select(@)...attr('x', (d, i) => @x(i))
rows = ...each(getRow)
```

But you need `getRow` to be a normal `->` function so that it gets the DOM element as `@` and you need the `attr` callback to be a bound `=>` function so `@x` works, right?

Two possibilities immediately come to mind:

1. Use the CoffeeScript form of the usual JavaScript `var that = this;` trick.
2. Use a named bound function for the `attr` callback.

The first one looks something like this:

```
that   = @
getRow = (row) ->
    cell = d3.select(@)
        .selectAll(".cell")
        .data(row)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d,i) -> that.x(i))
```

The second goes like this:

```
x_at_i = (d, i) => @x(i)
getRow = (row) ->
    cell = d3.select(@)
        .selectAll(".cell")
        .data(row)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", x_at_i)
```